# Creating a stored procedure with a select count

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am very new to creating procedures, looking for some guidance on my code.  I cant figure out how to output the number of students being mentored.  I am trying to output the following statement:    Create a stored procedure called MentoringCount which will display the professor name and the number of students he/she is mentoring. Sort the output by the professor name.

```
delimiter //
create procedure MentoringCount()
Begin
SELECT p.ProfessorName from professor p
join lab10.student_professor SP 
on (S.studentno = SP.studentno) 
where SP.mentored = 1
SELECT COUNT (Mentor)
FROM student_professor
order by p.ProfessorName;
END //
Delimiter ;

call mentoredStudents();
```

student table:

```
studentno
studentprogram
phoneno
age
firstname
lastname
```

professor table:

```
ProfessorId
ProfessorProgram
PhoneNo
Age
ProfessorName
```

student_professor table:

```
student_professor_id
ProfessorId
StudentNo
Mentor
```

Comment: You do it the same way you would write the query outside a stored procedure.

Comment: Should `Mentor` be `Mentored`?

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between doing this query in a stored procedure and normally.

You just need to join the tables and use `COUNT(*)` along with `GROUP BY`. Use `LEFT JOIN` so you'll get zero counts.

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE MentoringCount()
BEGIN
    SELECT p.professorName, IFNULL(COUNT(sp.student_professor_id), 0) AS students
    FROM professor AS p
    LEFT JOIN student_professor AS sp 
        ON sp.professorID = p.professorID AND sp.Mentored = 1
    GROUP BY p.professorID
    ORDER BY p.professorName
END;
//
```

Comment: +1 but couldn't IFNULL(COUNT(sp.student_professor_id), 0) be replaced with simple COUNT(*) ? Wouldn't it return zeroes just the same?

Comment: No, because `LEFT JOIN` returns a row from the `professor` table, with `NULL` in all the `student_professor` columns. `COUNT(*)` will count that row, so the count will be 1 even though no students.

Comment: It would be correct if using `INNER JOIN`.